# Create a countdown timer in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to use a countdown timer in my app.
I have this date

03-09-2011T20:54:18Z

Now I want to use countdown timer for this date. Can you please suggest if there is any method regarding this. I f I am not clear at any point please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn that timestamp into an NSDate* (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Then

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

will always give you the number of seconds between now and the date you care about. Then you can do something like:

```
#define SECONDS_IN_MINUTE 60
#define SECONDS_IN_HOUR (SECONDS_IN_MINUTE * 60)
#define SECONDS_IN_DAY (SECONDS_IN_HOUR * 24)

NSInteger days, hours, minutes, seconds;
days = interval / SECONDS_IN_DAY;
interval %= SECONDS_IN_DAY;
hours = interval / SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
interval %= SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
minutes = interval / SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
seconds %= SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
```

If you want it to update "live" every second then use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a delay of whatever period you want to update the display (or just 0.0 to do it every run loop)